# Can I use two different graphic cards together?

Tags: graphics-card

I am about to buy a graphic card (gtx 750 ) my computer already has an (amd 5400 ati) will they work together and perform a 3 GB graphic card performance or not

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about generic computer configuration, not gaming.

Comment: If you are running SLI, make sure your motherboard supports it. It is advised that you buy the same graphics card twice, therefore you can eliminate most conflicts that would normally arise. You need to make sure that your PSU is ready to handle SLI. If it's not DO NOT go with it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use two different graphics cards together, but only if they're made by the same manufacturer. Since you're trying to mix AMD and NVidia cards, it won't work. I would advise either buying another AMD card and using [AMD Crossfire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_CrossFireX), or alternatively buying a better AMD or NVidia graphics card to replace your current one.